# How do I prevent a UISearchBar from becoming top-most view when active?

Tags: ios, uikit, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I currently have the default `searchBar` of a `UISearchBarController` set as the `tableHeaderView` of a `UITableView`.

The `UITableView` instance is a property (`tableView`) of a `UITableViewController`, and on top of this I have a separate `UIViewController` which casts a drop shadow over any views below it. Like this:

[image: With Drop Shadow]

However, as soon as the `UISearchBar` becomes active, it becomes the topmost view, and I therefore lose the shadow on the search bar, like this:

[image: Without Shadow]

It seems that the `UISearchBar` is being brought to the front *after* the delegate method `searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:` is called, so I can't figure out when I can change  its position in the view hierarchy.

Is there any way I can alter this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to prevent the `UISearchBar` from being presented on top, the following needs to be set in the `UITableViewController`'s `viewDidLoad`

```
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
```

From the docs:

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL definesPresentationContext
```

> A Boolean value that indicates whether this view controller’s view is covered when the view controller or one of its descendants presents a view controller.
>   Availability